# Why do I have problems seeing YouTube?

Tags: 12.04, flash, youtube

Recently I moved to Ubuntu, I had Windows.
In Windows I could see very comfortable, but now in Ubuntu I can't. 
In the videos now, the picture and sound are out of sync.
Often you can't see the videos of the hughe out of sync.

I have a good computer, Lenovo G550 with 250Gb memory and 4Gb of Ram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you install the package called `ubuntu-restricted-extras`? You can do this in the Software Center or, if you prefer the to use the command-line, then by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

If you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, then verify that a Flash plugin is actually installed by checking for the `adobe-flashplugin` or `flashplugin-installer` packages. If neither is installed, install one of them. If you're running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, installing `adobe-flashplugin` is preferable. (But don't have them both installed at the same time.)

If you're running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu and you find that you have `flashplugin-installer` installed and the problem continues, then try removing it and replacing it with `adobe-flashplugin`.

If none of the above works, check to see if you're using the HTML5 beta on YouTube! by going to http://youtube.com/html5. Theoretically, and eventually, this should perform uniformly better on Ubuntu. But right now, it might not work well. So if it's turned off, you can try it and see if it works better. If it's turned on, try turning it off and seeing what happens.

If you have trouble doing any of the above, please post a comment here. If you do the above but it doesn't work, please edit your question to indicate that it didn't, and also to include the output of this command (which you should run in the Terminal): `dpkg -l | egrep 'flash|gnash|swf|spark'`

Comment: Thanks! I resolve the problem using the HTML5 of youtube.

Comment: Now is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Which browser are you using? I  find that using google-chrome provides the best overall Flash experience.

If you're using gnash, you'll want to remove that- and install Adobe's own proprietary format.   The installer is usually available via their own website: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Note: you can also install flashplugin-installer but all it basically does is perform a wget to the latest version at http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and run the installer