# why won't youtube videos play but all other websites work fine?

Tags: flash

I've tried everything I can think of, asking in a forum in spanish, uninstalling flash, looking for 64 bit versions, sorry but my mind just does not have another idea here and I'm  absolutely and totally frustrated.

Problem is that if I go to youtube.com and click on a video to watch, it won't play.  The player will load, meaning that I can see the black square with the play button and everything, but, a few seconds later, it just says "there has been an error, try again later" and every single time I try, the exact same problem occurs.  To make things even odder, if I go to whatever video website it'll work just fine, so you name it (vimeo, metacafe, etc.) they all work except youtube.

As I said I am extremely frustrated because I've tried everything I can think of, and nothing has had good results here.

Comment: Is this works well in windows  or any other software ? I faced similar problems when due to some settings in broadband router (I am unable to recollect now). Windows worked for 5 minutes..and then will not work, Ubuntu will not work at all

Comment: Are you at work, at school, or in a coffee shop?

Comment: Clear cache, cookie and Internet data from the browser and restart.

Comment: try diffrent browser

Comment: 1.- Yes it works in windows very well
2.- I'm home
3.- Cache cleared in Chromium and Firefox, no Results at all, still having issues
4.- Installig Epiphany, Slimboat and Dooble to see what happens

Comment: Did install  Slimboat and Dooble and the first video played in Youtube did play well, now right after that the second video did not work at all....  in Epiphany the videos work well so far

Comment: Do you have all your extensions off?  Try starting Firefox in safe mode, i.e. `firefox --safe-mode`.

Comment: Still not working in firefox safe mode.
Jesus this seems to be a tough one.

Comment: Yes, a tough one!  How about installing Google Chrome which has its own flash, to see how that works?

Comment: I already Have Chromium

Comment: Now i installed Chrome, and it did work at the beginning, before I logged in Youtube with the 1st video I tried, now, after I logged in it worked with the 1st video after, but then all other videos came up with the same problem, it happened just like it did before with all the other browsers, nothing seems to work here.

Comment: Ok guys, I give up here, there seems not to be a solution for this problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use FlashAid, a plug in for Firefox?  Also, have you looked at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/305324/youtube-videos-stopped-streaming?rq=1?

Comment: @Barsook flashaid was abandoned by the developer.

Comment: Oh, duh.  I should of known that.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for all your answers, @Thyago you hit in the bull's eye with that.  I went to connections and have changed MTU from auto to 1492 as you said, and that has solved the problem, I did not check your answer before because I wasn't home and wasn't using my pc, but that seems like fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are (or not are) in the HTML5 Video Player trial. Visit this link http://www.youtube.com/html5 if you are inside the trial just opt-out, if you are out, you may like to opt-in while flash is broken.

[image]

I would recommend you to check http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ and see what version of flash you have installed. You may also purge the plugin and upgrade Firefox.

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or try an alternative like Gnash:

```
sudo apt-get install gnash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to Re-install the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package, based on this answer to this question: [YouTube Videos Stopped Streaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305324/youtube-videos-stopped-streaming) and [Why do I have problems seeing YouTube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135212/why-do-i-have-problems-seeing-youtube/135213#135213)?